# Cortana stopped syncing text messages (sms) between Windows and my Android phones

Tags: sync, android, notifications, cortana, sms

So, Cortana syncing SMS and other app notifications was very handy while it worked. I got accustomed to it, but then one day it just stopped for no apparent reason. Form what I searched on the web, this a common (albeit sporadic) issue. I haven't found a remedy so far.

I tried re-installing Cortana on the phones, as well as removing devices from my Microsoft Account, but that didn't help.

How do I get sms syncing working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it by doing "Clear" at "Change what Cortana knows about me in the Cloud" in "Permission & History" settings. After that I also re-installed Cortana on the phone, not sure that stepped was required, too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cortana has been acting up for the last couple days, I'm guessing there's a problem with MS servers, not your device.